# Parsing and editing html using DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, edit

How to edit HTML page using PHP DOM Parser? I have a page on my site that I want to edit. I tried these things...

```
 foreach($html->find('div[class=doc-metadata]') as $data){  //bunch of HTML codes that contain a link to be edited. 
      $metadata = $data->children();        

        }
```

The page contains a link that I want to edit the `href`. Say...

```
<a href="this/is/random/link">Link to edit</a>
```

I tried this.

```
   foreach($html->find('div[class=doc-metadata]') as $data){    

     $link= $data->find('a');      
     $link->href = null; //set to null or change it completely (i think)  

    }
```

But after that line, I am completely lost. I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: So, are you looking for [`saveHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)?

Comment: hmm by the way after parsing, i want to save it to an array. From there, find the <a> tag and change the href.

Comment: Could you describe what you expect as the output?

Answer (score 0):

To change an attribute of an element, you can use [setAttribute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php).

```
$link->setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

After doing this, you might need the HTML output of DOM. You can do this by, saveHTML().

```
print $html->saveHTML();
```